# starting session in ear

Tags: java, http, session, jboss

I have an ear file having 3 war files(admin app, ehs app and visa app)  deployed in jboss cluster enviornment.There is only 1 login and the user is logging  into admin app. FRom there, user clicks ehs app link or visa app link.

The problem is after log in, if the user clicks on visa app link, the session is null and hence navigation not happening.

This was working fine in non clustered enviornmrnt but not working in Jboss cluster.

How can i start a session in visa app when the user logs in to admin app?.

Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you need a "Single Sign On" functionality across these applications? Or just cluster node affinity across applications (should be configurable in your load balancer)?

Comment: Problem is. for Admin app if session is getting created in Node1, visa app session is getting created in Node2.These are separate war files with different context. Can we configure the load balancer to start both contexts session in the same node?

Answer (score 0):

As a simple (not necessarily ideal) solution you should be able to configure your load balancer to keep each user on the same node across applications. What is your load balancer?